# On LMDE 2, why is my screen dimming after only a few seconds?

Tags: linux-mint, cinnamon, power-management, lmde

I'm running LMDE with Cinnamon 2.4.7 and I cannot get the screen to stay on (undimmed) for longer than a few seconds of inactivity.

What setting am I missing?